# jupyter, scope of variable only in loop

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a small code in jupyter notebook:

```
for col in df:
    # fill NaN using most frequent values
    df[col].fillna(df[col].value_counts().index[0], inplace=True)
    print(df[col].isnull().sum())
print(df.isnull().sum())
```

And here is a problem, my results looks that:

```
0
0
0
MSSubClass         0
MSZoning           0
LotFrontage      227
```

In a *for loop* DataFrame filling all null values, but after for loop my dataFrame has null values again.

I checked this in PyCharm and works fine (after loop I haven't any null values).

Question: Why does jupyter notebook work in this way? How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sharing the exact code or did you do any modifications to simplify the issue?

Comment: I'm sharing the exact part of code. Under link there is whole function https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/GZVxMTKWCQ/

Comment: Did u figured out the issue? It does look weird